# Pandas join (merge?) dataframes, keep only unique indicies

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a data frame with date index. There are a few dates that somehow went missing. This I’ll call dataframe `A`.  I have another data frame with the dates in question included. I’ll call this dataframe `B`.

I’d like to merge two dataframes:

Keep all indices of `A` and join it with `B`, but **I don’t want any of the rows in `B` that share an index with `A`**. That is, I want only the rows missing from `A` returned from `B`.

How is this most easily achieved?

Note:

This behavior is true for a database of data I have.  I’ll be doing it roughly 400 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive you need [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
B.loc[B.index.difference(A.index)]
```

EDIT:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10)}, index=pd.date_range('2019-02-01', periods=10))
B = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10, 20)}, index=pd.date_range('2019-01-27', periods=10))
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([A, B.loc[B.index.difference(A.index)]]).sort_index()
print (df)
             A
2019-01-27  10
2019-01-28  11
2019-01-29  12
2019-01-30  13
2019-01-31  14
2019-02-01   0
2019-02-02   1
2019-02-03   2
2019-02-04   3
2019-02-05   4
2019-02-06   5
2019-02-07   6
2019-02-08   7
2019-02-09   8
2019-02-10   9
```

---

```
df1= pd.concat([A, B])
df1 = df1[~df1.index.duplicated()].sort_index()
print (df1)
             A
2019-01-27  10
2019-01-28  11
2019-01-29  12
2019-01-30  13
2019-01-31  14
2019-02-01   0
2019-02-02   1
2019-02-03   2
2019-02-04   3
2019-02-05   4
2019-02-06   5
2019-02-07   6
2019-02-08   7
2019-02-09   8
2019-02-10   9
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading the question correctly, what you want is

```
B[~B.index.isin(A.index)]
```

For example:

```
In [192]: A
Out[192]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1, 2, 4, 5]

In [193]: B
Out[193]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [194]: B[~B.index.isin(A.index)]
Out[194]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [3]
```

To use the data from `A` when it's there, and otherwise take it from `B`, you could then do

```
pd.concat([A, B[~B.index.isin(A.index)]).sort_index()
```

or, assuming that `A` contains no null elements that you want to keep, you could take a different approach and go for something like

```
pd.DataFrame(A, index=B.index).fillna(B)
```

Comment: This basically is what I want yes. Then I can merge the two DataFrames once B has been indexed this way.

Comment: I don't really see what you mean by "merging". By definition of the index, there is no data to take from `A`, thus nothing to merge.

Comment: I don’t really want them “merged”, which is why I wasn’t sure what to title the post. But I want them concatenated and then sorted (yes I know pandas can concat and will sort index). But for lack of a concise term, I wrote “merge”

Comment: So, use the data from `A` when it's there, and if not, use it from `B` instead?

Comment: yes that’s correct. I think both answers will filter the data appropriately and I can concatenate and sort them by index. Unless there’s a better way?

Comment: Although you could definitely use `DataFrame.join` to this effect (if nothing else then through a few steps), following your own idea (and @jezrael's approach), it sounds like you want `pd.concat([A, B.loc[B.index.difference(A.index)]]).sort_index()`. Otherwise, you could let `merged = pd.DataFrame(A, index=B.index)` and do `merged[merged.isnull()] = B` (assuming that `A` contains no null elements).

Comment: @fuglede - Or use concat and filter by `index.duplicated`

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks, makes sense; clever. Guess it'll cost a bit more memory, but chances are that won't make a difference. Let me just add the other approaches to the answer.

Comment: In fact, `pd.DataFrame(A, index=B.index).fillna(B)` seems like the best of both worlds.

Comment: hmmm, not 100% sure about last solution if working if different length in both df

Comment: @jezrael, as I read the question, `A.index` is a subset of `B.index`.

Comment: I should note, when the data is not in A, it does not produce NaN, because the entire index is missing. So I think both answers here have potential. I’ll try them tonight

Answer (score 2):

Although there alread good anwer I want to share this one because it's so short

```
pd.concat([A, B]).drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I’ve used something very similar to address other needs in the past, I’m surprised I didn’t think of this. I guess I just thought there should be a “join” to take only the unique elements from two datasets (but then... I know that’s not really a “join”). Maybe I’ll try this first.

Comment: Problem of this answer is need remove duplicates by index, so `.drop_duplicates(keep='first')` cannot be uaed, because it remove dupes by all columns, not sure if need it. If need remove dupes by index need `df1 = df1[~df1.index.duplicated()].sort_index()` check my answer for solution with sample data.

Comment: @jezrael I didn’t realize that behavior would be applied per column. That’s helpful to know.